# Logic to give me first row if a certain condition is met in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that gives me multiple rows of data and I need logic that gives me only the first row if total qty ordered is more than qty available. Here's an example of the data:

```
Order Number  Qty Ordered  SKU   Qty Ordered  Qty Available    Total Qty Ordrered
   1             4         jhr       4            5                   7
   2             1         jhr       1            5                   7
   3             2         jhr       2            5                   7
```

Since the total qty ordered is 7 and there are only 5 qty available I only want to see the first row of data.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Define 'first' please.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `TOP 1` at the beginning of your query.

`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table`

Comment: Same as the answer for JaydipJ's answer. Missing ORDER BY renders the query non predictable.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this query:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Table
WHERE [Total Qty Ordrered] > [Qty Available] 
ORDER BY [ORDER Number]
```

Comment: Without ORDER BY the order of the rows in a result set is NOT defined. TOP 1 may return record #1 for the first execution and row #2 for the subsequent executions. Some explanation would be nice too, code only answers are considered as low quality answers.

Comment: Thanks @Pred Updated ANS with Order by Clause